# Remote control devices via infra-red light from our bodies

Tags: infrared-radiation

We can remote control devices via infra-red light.

This light also radiate every living organism.

If we could control our radiation, could we remote control these devices?

Comment: I think you already answer your question. do you know how to control IR radiation from a living organism?

Answer (score 2):

the IR radiation from a living organism comes from its metabolic rate, which establishes its heat production rate and hence its temperature.

To send signals via your IR output would require you to somehow modulate your metabolic rate. the time constant for that will be of order ~hundreds of seconds which means the bit rate would be extremely slow.

Also, since your well-being depends on your metabolic rate, sending a zero bit via IR means reducing your metabolism, which might not be a good idea.

Comment: Easy! Just keep a square of sheet metal handy. It should be a little bit bigger than your head. Hold it up to block the sensor's view of your face every time you want to activate the remote whatever-it-is.  P.S., This will work better if air in the room is cool, and you're wearing heavy clothes.  If you're a nudist, then you will need a larger sheet of metal.

Comment: Don't hold the sheet too close to your body. In time, it will assume the same temperature as your body, in which case shielding your face with it will not "turn off" the IR beam.